Battery showing "not charging" and status showing "pending-charge"
I am new to Ubuntu and I installed Ubuntu as standalone OS on my brand-new Lenovo laptop and using it for past 3 months. To check if my adapter has problem, I plugged in another adapter, but same problem persist. This issue has started today, before this it was charging normal even at 100% charge the bolt/flash icon always showed up.
If I plugged in an adapter, then % of battery remains stationary. It is showing 95% from last 1 hr, but if I remove the adapter it discharges and % decreases. But again, on plugging in adapter the % of battery won't increase.
Is there any solution to this issue?
Used following command: upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
and this is the what I got:
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               SMP
model:                L20M2PF0
serial:               1815
power supply:         yes
updated:              Monday 03 June 2024 03:40:49 PM (10 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               pending-charge
warning-level:       none
energy:              35.73 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         37.31 Wh
energy-full-design:  38 Wh
energy-rate:         0.773 W
voltage:             8.681 V
charge-cycles:       74
percentage:          95%
capacity:            98.1842%
technology:          lithium-polymer
icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

It may be the connector in the laptop itself, strictly a hardware issue.
